# Runtime blending large images (Java/JOGL/Processing)

Tags: java, gpu, processing, jogl

I need to alpha blend 2700x1600 images at runtime.  It's essentially a slideshow, though with multiple "decks" running simultaneously.  Each column in this diagram represents a program state at any moment in time:

```
imageA1 <-blend-> imageA2 <-blend-> imageA3 ...
imageB1 <-blend-> imageB2 <-blend-> imageB3 ...
imageC1 <-blend-> imageC2 <-blend-> imageC3 ...
imageD1 <-blend-> imageD2 <-blend-> imageD3 ...
imageE1 <-blend-> imageE2 <-blend-> imageE3 ...
imageF1 <-blend-> imageF2 <-blend-> imageF3 ...
```

Not totally surprisingly, I'm having problems keeping my framerate up.  I've tried doing the blending on an offscreen buffer, but that hasn't seemed to help much if any.  Are there any general strategies for working with images this large that might apply to this situation?  Something to leverage the graphics card as much as possible, perhaps?

This is my basic strategy (very simplified code, Processing rather than Java) as of right now:

```
PImage a = loadImage("imageA.png");
PImage b = loadImage("imageB.png");
PGraphics buffer = createGraphics(width, height, OPENGL);

void draw () {
    buffer.beginDraw();
    buffer.tint(255, 200);
    buffer.image(a, 0, 0);
    buffer.tint(255, 100);
    buffer.image(b, 0, 0);
    buffer.endDraw();
    image(buffer, 0, 0);
}
```

I'm using Java/[Processing](http://processing.org/), but advice in raw JOGL is welcome.

I'm also having a bit of trouble managing memory; each of these images uncompressed is ~17MB (2700x1600x4 bytes), and there are a total of ~60 images I'll be blending (not all simultaneously!).  I have strategies in mind for the memory issue that are outside the scope of this question, but I include it here in case there is a clever way to balance memory usage between the computer's memory and the graphics card's.

(Extra info, for those who care: My understanding is that Processing's [image()](http://processing.org/reference/image_.html) calls (which draw image objects to the screen) uses JOGL for its underlying implementation.  This understanding comes from looking at the source for Processing's [PGraphics.imageImpl() method](http://code.google.com/p/processing/source/browse/trunk/processing/core/src/processing/core/PGraphics.java#3620), which when using the PGraphicsOpenGL renderer (I am), ends up at native JOGL calls within [PGraphicsOpenGL.rawPolys()](http://code.google.com/p/processing/source/browse/trunk/processing/core/src/processing/opengl/PGraphicsOpenGL.java#2370).)

Comment: Could you please split this question down? If you have difficulty with a particular part, post a question about it specifically, with a section on what you have tried.

Comment: Must it be Processing/Java ? This is almost off topic, but have you considered MaxMSP/**Jitter** ? Jitter matrices are pretty fast and you can use gl if you want. If the patch visual programming paradigm is an issue you can use C++, script in JavaScript or extend MaxObject in Java(I remember this is the case in Max5, not sure if it's still there in Max6), but the idea is Jitter deals pretty fast with pixels

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza, yep, jitter is tailored to this kind of thing.  unfortunately, this is just one component of a much larger application, and rewriting in jitter just ain't happening ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your worst enemy will be disk I/O. In the past, I have used a memory buffer which held all the images that needed to be processed. In your case, that buffer would be a slice of your 60 images... say a 10 image slice buffer.

Producer Thread-1:

load image from disk--->|10 image Buffer|----->process image in a FIFO manner

Consumer Thread-2:
image ready for display --->|Display buffer|----->paint image

Also, you could profile your code with JProfiler to see other bottlenecks.

Comment: I've found that I can actually load all of my images on init, if I set my JVM to -Xmx1536M, but allowing Java to allocate that much memory brings my OS to a crawl, and affects responsiveness within the program.  Users will be able to scrub quickly between images (added a diagram to my question), so while I could load images on-demand in one thread and display them on another, I'm concerned that the load operations and GC cleanup will leave me in the same sluggish state...

Comment: The GC cleanup concern you can't help... I mean your object has no other references and memory is being re-claimed. As for load operations, I am hesitant to advise you to mess around with Java bindings for OpenCL. You really need to profile your code first in order to know where the bottlenecks are.